# Will there be a performance increase if using custom attribute selectors instead of long mixed class/tag selectors with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, long-integer, custom-attributes

I noticed that some of developers in our team are creating long jQuery selectors like:

```
'div.someclass > span.someotherclass ...'
```

I know, that jQuery will try to use native DOM methods for classes and tags, but I think if it would be more efficient to use something lite this:

```
'[data-gid="my-element-group"]'
```

instead of those long mixed class/tag selectors.

**Will custom attribute selectors be faster than long class/tag selectors or it depends on circumstances? Which approach to choose for a Javascript-heavy website?**

P.S. I guess, those long selectors are also dangerous if HTML designers and Javascript coders are working separately - designer may break Javascript functionality just by changing CSS classes or moving tags around. But if they see ids and data-gids, they can leave them alone, and that should be much safer... but will it sacrifice performance?

P.P.S. I don't care about invalid HTML4 because of custom attributes, the performance is much more important for most of my clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longer selectors should be faster. Here's an example. Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="testDiv">
    <span class="testSpan"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span data-group="testSpan"></span>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
var elems1 = $("div.testDiv > span.testSpan");
var elems2 = $("[data-group='testSpan']");
```

Here's the results from a [quick test](http://jsperf.com/long-selectors-vs-data):

[image]

However, it's worth noting that in the real world the difference is going to be minimal and you should use whichever suits you best.

You could make your `data-*` selector slightly better (performance-wise) by making it more specific:

```
var elems = $("span[data-group='testSpan']");
```

But another quick test reveals (for me, in Chrome 15 at least) that the longer selectors still win.

I think in older browsers with no support for `querySelectorAll`, the difference will be even more pronounced in favour of the longer selectors, which can use the native `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Well, this proves that I was wrong. Great explanation, thanks.